# Should I take initial velocity and acceleration due to gravity positive or negative in motion in 1 dimension?

Tags: kinematics, acceleration

I was studying motion in one dimension, my sir taught that when a body is thrown upwards from the ground it will have a negative initial velocity and negative acceleration and when it will be falling after reaching maximum height, it will have positive velocity and positive acceleration.

But when I studied from a channel in YouTube, he said that acceleration due to gravity will be always negative, so when a body is thrown upwards, it will have a positive initial velocity and when it falls after reaching maximum height, it will have negative velocity.

I am so confused because of this, can anyone please tell me the concept behind this?

Comment: It's just a convention. You can choose any but you should stick with it throughout the problem.

Comment: Either your "sir" was incorrect or you misunderstood him.  It is obvious that the force due to gravity always points downward, whether you consider "downward" to be the positive or negative direction.

Comment: The statement that the acceleration changes from positive to negative is just WRONG.

Comment: @alephzero, many times I've had students tell me that when I throw a ball straight up, the acceleration becomes zero at the top of the ball's travel.  I told them that if they ever see that, they need to contact me, because we have just discovered anti-gravity, as the ball will hang in mid air under those conditions.  Due to such comments from students, I think there is a lot of confusion regarding the difference between velocity and acceleration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already pointed out in the comments, whether you consider "upward" or "downwards" positive or negative is just convention. As far as I know, in most cases we consider "down" to be negative so acceleration is always negative (since gravity makes things fall/accelerate downwards).

You could however also choose "downwards" to be positive, the only important thing is to be consistent throughout the problem. Thus the statement that the sign or direction of acceleration changes is wrong.